# Adding charts to a Flask webapp

Tags: python, flask, data-visualization

I created a web app with Flask where I'll be showing data, so I need charts for it.

The problem is that I don't really know how to do that, so I'm trying to find the best way to do that. I tried to use a Javascript charting library on my frontend and send the data to the chart using *SocketIO*, but the problem is that I need to send that data frequently and at a certain point I'll be having a lot of data, so sending each time a huge load of data through AJAX/SocketIO would not be the best thing to do.

To solve this, I had this idea: could I generate the chart from my backend, instead of sending data to the frontend? I think it would be the better thing to do, since I won't have to send the data to the frontend each time and there won't be a need to generate a ton of data each time the page is loaded, since the chart will be processed on the frontend.

So would it be possible to generate a chart from my Flask code in Python and visualize it on my webpage? Is there a good library do that?

Comment: Have a look at Bokeh or Plotly packages, both support graph and charts.

Comment: Yes, plotly does but it's hard to use it on Python, since the library had been built for Javascript

Comment: Yeah well, I gave more than 1 suggestion in my first comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use dash is a python library for web charts

Comment: Yeah, Dash is good, only problem is that at a certain point i'll need to have authentication on my app, and Dash only provides basic authentication

Comment: I didn't work so much with Dash but for more informations you can look on youtube( on setdex) .He is explaining very well how is working.That guy has 12 tutorials about dash

Comment: Yeah, i actually discovered Dash 1 year ago from Sentdex :)

Comment: Please vote if you consider that i helped you